# How to make an alert for the correct or incorrect answer in a quiz game?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble displaying the correct alert for a quiz game that I'm making. The correct_answer and incorrect_answers from an API are placed in an array that are displayed randomly in the game.html page. Not sure what to do to get the correct result on the page.

This is my script.js file:

```
window.onload = sendApiRequest

async function sendApiRequest(){
    let response = await fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=9&difficulty=easy&type=multiple");
    console.log(response)
    let data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
    useApiData(data)
}

function randomAnswers(array){
    let copyOfArray = Array.from(array);
      return function() {
        if (copyOfArray.length < 1) {
            copyOfArray = Array.from(array);
        } 
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * copyOfArray.length);
        const item = copyOfArray[index];
        copyOfArray.splice(index, 1);
        return item;
    };
}

function useApiData(data){
    document.querySelector("#category").innerHTML = `Category: ${data.results[0].category}`
    document.querySelector("#difficulty").innerHTML = `Difficulty: ${data.results[0].difficulty}`
    document.querySelector("#question").innerHTML = `Question: ${data.results[0].question}`

    const chooseFromArray = randomAnswers([data.results[0].incorrect_answers[2], data.results[0].incorrect_answers[0],
    data.results[0].incorrect_answers[1], data.results[0].correct_answer]);

    document.querySelector("#answer1").innerHTML = `${chooseFromArray()}`;
    document.querySelector("#answer2").innerHTML = `${chooseFromArray()}`;
    document.querySelector("#answer3").innerHTML = `${chooseFromArray()}`;
    document.querySelector("#answer4").innerHTML = `${chooseFromArray()}`;

}

let correct_answer = document.querySelector("#answer1")
let incorrect_answers1 = document.querySelector("#answer2")
let incorrect_answers2 = document.querySelector("#answer3")
let incorrect_answers3 = document.querySelector("#answer4")

correct_answer.addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert("You got it right!")
    sendApiRequest()
})

incorrect_answers1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("You got it wrong!")
  sendApiRequest()
})

incorrect_answers2.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("You got it wrong!")
  sendApiRequest()
})

incorrect_answers3.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("You got it wrong!")
  sendApiRequest()
})
```

And this is my game.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Trivia Game</title>
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <h2>Your Game Has Begun!</h2>
        <p id="category"></p>
        <p id="difficulty"></p>
        <p id="question"></p>
        <button id="answer1" value="A">A</button>
        <button id="answer2">B</button>
        <button id="answer3">C</button>
        <button id="answer4">D</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any assistance or direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific about what behavior you want to see and what behavior you're getting instead.

Comment: @NathanWiles basically the 4 answers are displayed randomly which is what I want every time there is a new question from the API. The trouble I'm having, is getting the corresponding alert to post to the appropriate answer whether it's a right or wrong answer. What I'm getting is the alert for "You got it right...." to always post when the first answer is clicked whether it's the right or wrong answer. Hope that explains it.